# Update Mint Price function of my Smart Contract on the Frontend

Tags: solidity, nft, mint, price

Good morning! My Smart Contract has a function to update the price once totalSupply reach 2000 tokens minted. I added a function in the front end but i think is not clean at all. Works well on my Dapp (with React) but... have you got any idea to make it cleaner? I created a function inside the mint function to replicate the Updateprice from the Smart Contract, because i couldn't call the Smart Contract function directly from the contract.methods.... Any suggestion? As I say is working already, but i'm pretty sure that i can get a cleaner code. Thank you so much in advice!

**Smart contract:**

```
  uint128 public publicSalePrice = 0.01 ether;

 //Function to update publicSalePrice once 2.000 have been minted

  function updatePrice() internal returns (uint256) {
  return publicSalePrice = totalSupply() < 2000 ? 0.01 ether : 0.03 ether;
  }
         
 //Function Public Mint.

 function publicSaleMint(uint256 _quantity) external payable callerIsUser {
    require(sellingStep == Step.PublicSale, "Public sale is not  activated");
    require(totalSupply() + _quantity <= MAX_PUBLIC, "Max supply exceeded");
    require(totalSupply() + _quantity <= MAX_SUPPLY, "Max supply exceeded");
    require(msg.value >= updatePrice() * _quantity, "Not enought funds");
    _safeMint(msg.sender, _quantity);
}
```

**NOW the Frontend**(function setprice is where mintrate is calculated). I also created a variable nuevoprice to get the totalSupply for the Smart Contract:

```
async function mint() {
var _mintAmount = Number(document.querySelector("[name=amount]").value);
var nuevoprice = Number(await contract.methods.totalSupply().call());
var maxsupply = 10000;
function setprice() {
 if(nuevoprice < 2000){
    return Web3.utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether');}
 else if(nuevoprice <= maxsupply){
  return Web3.utils.toWei('0.03', 'ether');}
   } 
var mintRate = Number(setprice());
var totalAmount = mintRate * _mintAmount;
await Web3Alc.eth.getMaxPriorityFeePerGas().then((tip) => {
    Web3Alc.eth.getBlock('pending').then((block) => {
      var baseFee = Number(block.baseFeePerGas);
      var maxPriority = Number(tip);
      var maxFee = baseFee + maxPriority;
contract.methods.publicSaleMint(_mintAmount)
.send({from: account, 
    value: String(totalAmount),
    maxFeePerGas: maxFee,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: maxPriority});
  });
})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of points to note but nothing major.

```
    require(totalSupply() + _quantity <= MAX_PUBLIC, "Max supply exceeded");
    require(totalSupply() + _quantity <= MAX_SUPPLY, "Max supply exceeded");
```

If one of `MAX_PUBLIC` and `MAX_SUPPLY` is always larger than the other, you can remove one statement.

There is a chance `setprice` will return `undefined` when the sale has concluded, breaking further calculations.

Consider removing gas fee estimations from your request. Metamask and other providers will internally calculate these values when requesting a transaction signature.

Comment: Thank you so much Milk! I will update with your advices. Thank you :D